# Unix find command directory hints

Tags: linux, macos, unix, solaris

I am an active user of the find command, similar to the below format:

```
find . -name '*servername*' -exec zgrep -l 'identifier'  {} \;
```

Suppose I have a hint that the target file may be in directory named abc, is it possible in find command or any of its combinations to accept hints?

For example, if the search first searches in subdirectories named abc there are more chances to find the results, and I can break the search operation if needed.

I am looking for some similar command:

```
find --hint dir1|pattern1 . -name '*servername*' -exec zgrep -l 'identifier'  {} \;
```

Comment: @krzyk unfortunately I don't have a fixed directory structure. This subdirectory can be at any nested level and this is not always for directory name some time I require to search in file name also. For example first I search ssl files or access files then I search for details.

Comment: Are you going to search every directory anyway, or stop after one or a set number of results have been found?

Comment: I will stop after few matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
find $(find . -type d -name abc
      ) -name '*servername*' -exec zgrep -l 'identifier' {} +
```

Demo:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/demo
$ cd /tmp/demo
$ mkdir -p a/b/abc 
$ echo identifier | gzip > a/b/abc/one_servername.gz
$ find $(find . -type d -name abc
        ) -name '*servername*'-exec zgrep -l 'identifier' {} +
./a/b/abc/one_servername.gz
```

Comment: No it didn't work 
This is what I got:

find: paths must precede expression:  -exec
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

Comment: That means there are no subdirectories named `abc` so the hint is incorrect.

Comment: the sub-directory is there

Comment: Sample test added to my reply. What shell interpreter are you using and on what OS?

Comment: This must be my OS specific issue, I am using Linux centOS 6 and bash terminal (connected from Win using mRemote). Even above command I get same error which works fine as per above comment.

Comment: `Centos 6` and `bash` are very mainstream environments. My command line should work with no error, assuming there is at least one directory named `abc`. Please copy paste the exact command you typed and its result at the end of your question. Make sure you do not pollute the bash command with Windows "CRLF" line terminator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple search directories in find, it will look in them in the order provided:

```
find dir1 dir2 dir3 -name '*servername*' -exec zgrep -l 'identifier'  {} \;
```